# why does my bitbake task only show a dependency when the task is run but not when the project as a whole is run

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I have a .bbappend file `rpi-bootfiles.bbappend` that runs a task named `do_after_deploy` which only seems to run if I manually run the task `rpi-bootfiles:do_deploy` within the original recipe `rpi-bootfiles.bb`. The task `do_after_deploy` does not execute when the project as a whole is run even though the dependent task `do_deploy` runs during the main project. I checked the dependencies of the main project and the single recipe using the command `bitbake -g -u taskexp <target>` and found that `do_after_deploy` is only listed as a dependent task if I use the *target* = `rpi-bootfiles`. Why would my task not be listed in the dependency explorer when I run bitbake on the entire project? I have attached screenshots which show the dependencies of the `do_deploy` task which should run before my task. The first screenshot is the task dependency explorer with command `bitbake -g -u taskexp rpilinux-image` which is the main project. The second screenshot is the task dependency explorer with command `bitbake -g -u taskexp rpi-bootfiles` which is a single recipe of the main project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `bbappend` file that contains the `do_after_deploy` task ?